# call a javascript prototype object method from main class

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var log = function (e, clear) {
  if (clear === true) {
    this.clear();
  }
  console.log(e);
};
log.prototype = {
  clear: function () {
    console.clear();
  }
};
```

i'm calling like this.

```
log('hi', true);
```

it says clear is undefined. I also tried log.clear(); but same undefined.

Comment: Are you using `new`?

Comment: Need to instantiate the object with `new` so the constructor gets called

Comment: var log = new log();

Comment: `new Log.clear()` - Furthermore your log wrapper is weak. It should take a variable number of arguments, like printf in C

Comment: use new or Object.create() instead of just calling it

Comment: could be written as var log=console.log.bind(console) and be faster, more flexible, simpler...

Comment: More info on constructor functions and prototype here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write it like this

```
function Log(e, clear) {

  // make `new` optional
  if (!(this instanceof Log)) {
    return new Log(e, clear);
  }

  // clear?
  if (clear === true) {
    this.clear();
  }

  // log
  console.log(e);
}

Log.prototype.clear = function clear() {
  console.clear();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke a function, without `new` operator, `this` will refer the default global object (in browsers `window` object), where `clear` function is not defined. That is why you are getting this error.

To make `this` refer an object created from the `log` constructor function, you need to call it like this.

```
new log("Error", true);
```

Now, JavaScript creates an Object and `this` will refer that newly created object. And when you do `this.clear`, it will first check if the current object has `clear` method, which it doesn't have. So, it will go up the prototype chain to find it in `log`'s prototype and that function will be executed.

Comment: previously i was not using prototype, and it was working fine.

Comment: function log(e, clear) {
            clear = typeof clear === 'boolean' ? clear : false;
            if (clear === true)
                console.clear();
            console.log(e);
        }

Comment: @PritpalSingh You don't use `this` in this function :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simply putting a breakpoint on the `this.clear()`, or even just examining `this` in the console when the error terminated script execution, would have shown you that `this` was not set correctly.

The classic technique for defending against constructors **not** being called with `new` is

```
if (!(this instanceof log)) { return new log(e, clear); }
```

Minor point, but `clear === true` is semi-redundant. Boolean variables are themselves test conditions, without being compared to `true` or `false`.